# How to filter a list from sublist

Tags: c#, checkbox, listbox

I have listbox which is bind with a datasource. I have hold all the items of this listbox in to a generic type list as following code.

```
List<FRReportRow> lstreport = lstSelectRows.Items.Cast<FRReportRow>().ToList();
```

I have done some code of mouse click for multiextended selection of listbox. These selected items are in same type of another list as following.

```
List<FRReportRow> reportRow = 
     lstSelectRows.SelectedItems.Cast<FRReportRow>().ToList();
```

Now I have a checkbox which returns only those items which are not in the `reportRow` list when i checked the checkbox and I unchecked the checkbox it returns full list as `lstreprot`. So How can i filter items from `lstreport`?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You want to get selected items from `lstreport` list?

Comment: NO..I want to filter "lstreport" list which not contains "reportRow" list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get rows which exist only in `lstreport` list (i.e. not selected rows):

```
IEnumerable<FRReportRow> notSelectedRows = lstreport.Except(reportRow);
```